# Angular 2 - Can't stop Observable (unsubscribe() throws undefined)

Tags: angular

I would like to executes `unsubscribe()` once I exit the view and push to the next one. However, `this.updateRoute.unsubscribe()` throws `undefined` Any reason for that ?

```
   ngOnInit(){
   //The following executes each 10 seconds
    let updateRoute = Observable.timer(0,10000);
    this.updateRoute = updateRoute.subscribe(update =>{
    this.updateRouteTaken(this.driverLocation)
     })
    }


ngOnDestroy(){
//this throws undefined
this.updateRoute.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: will you please post full component code ?

Comment: What do you mean by "throws undefined"? What is the error message? What version of rxjs?

Comment: i dont think `.subscribe() ` returns the object itself? why do you override it in the 4th line?`